# Using TensorFlow to predict a number using three or more input numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm very new to using TensorFlow in Python, and need to solve a problem which seems fairly straightforward, but I can't find anything helpful online to even point me in the right direction.

Essentially, I have a dataset containing sets of four integer variables - let's call them a, b, c and x. I'd like to be able to train a model to predict x when given only a, b and c. All of the numbers are integers between 0 and 1000, but ideally I'd like the flexibility to be able to use decimal numbers for all four numbers, including x.

Most of the material I've read online has focused on assigning a category given a number of input variables, rather than predicting a number.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial which might get me started on this? It seems like such a simple task, but after searching for hours I haven't been able to find anything. I suspect I'm just using the wrong jargon.

Comment: It depends on what the data means. Is it like predicting the prices of houses based on sq.ft value and number of bedrooms ?

Comment: Very similar to that Mohan - I'm hoping to be able to predict plant growth indicators based on weather conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [**regression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) problem (i.e. predicting a continuous value), not a categorisation problem (labelling from a set of discrete values).

The tensorflow docs have a number of [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/regression_examples) demonstrating regression.